# Drupal - What is Server and index in Search Api Drupal

Tags: search, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I spent 2 days studying "Seach Api Module" in Drupal

```
    Somebody can explain for me , What is Purpose of "Server"
 and "Index" in "Search APi Module",
    Why we need to Create "Server" and "Index", and We Can I find them, Does 
"Index" create a xml file like Solr Server
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Server** is what's doing the searching and where the content defined by the index is being held. An example would be [Database Search](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_db) or Search API Solr.

The **Index** defines what fields are going to be indexed, as well as other settings pertaining to your search such as facets. It is tied to a type of content, like node, taxonomy terms, or users.

If you have Search API installed, you can find the settings at example.com/admin/config/search/search_api. There you can add your Server and define your Index.[image]